# how can I get to the methods in the "parent"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this object.
fieldsCreator's members hold creator methods for each field.
My question is how can I call the creator method inside `fieldsCreators` as described below:

```
var obj={
    creator:function(ch) {
        ....
        ....
        ....
    },
    fieldsCreators:{
            INVITER: function () {
                return creator('a'); //HOW DO I CALL creator METHOD?
            },
            CUSTOMER: function () {
                return creator('b'); //HOW DO I CALL creator METHOD?
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a pattern like this:

```
var obj = (function() {

    var methods = {
        creator: function(ch) {

        },
        fieldsCreators:{
            INVITER: function () {
                return methods.creator('a');
            },
            CUSTOMER: function () {
                return methods.creator('b');
            }
        }
    };

    return methods;
})();
```

How is this useful? Let's say you wanted to give all your methods access to a variable, but only visible inside of obj. You couldn't do this if obj was just an object, it needs a function's scope. For example:

```
var obj = (function() {

    // everything declared with var won't be visible to the rest
    // of the application, which is good encapsulation practice.
    // You only return what you want to be publicly exposed.
    var MYPRIVATEINFO = "cheese";

    var methods = {
        creator: function(ch) {
            // you have access to MYPRIVATEINFO here
            // but the rest of the application doesn't
            // even know about it.    
        },
        fieldsCreators:{
            INVITER: function () {
                return methods.creator('a');
            },
            CUSTOMER: function () {
                return methods.creator('b');
            }
        }
    };

    return methods;
})();
```

If you don't want to have to name your object, you COULD structure it like this, which is why having a private environment is key:

```
var obj = (function() {

    var creator = function(ch) {

    };


    return {
        // if you wish, you can still expose the creator method to the public:
        creator: creator,
        fieldsCreators: {
            INVITER: function () {
                return creator('a');
            },
            CUSTOMER: function () {
                return creator('b');
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Why is your example is better solution then Amir Raminfar's solution?

Comment: It allows you to have a private environment. I will update the post on how to do this.

Comment: Its really the same thing except as Eli said you get to choose which methods are private and public. But again using 'methods' is like using 'obj'

Answer (score 2):

Does `obj.creator(...)` not work?

You are defining an instance called 'obj' so you should be able to use that name.

EDIT--
This is probably what you want -

```
var obj={
    creator:function(ch) {
        ....
        ....
        ....
    },
    self : this,
    fieldsCreators:{
            INVITER: function () {
                return self.creator('a'); //HOW DO I CALL creator METHOD?
            },
            CUSTOMER: function () {
                return self.creator('b'); //HOW DO I CALL creator METHOD?
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to get to creator method without the obj? I don't want to depend the fieldsCreators in the variable name.

Comment: There is but you have singleton which doesn't make sense to not use obj. But I think I know what you mean. Look at my edit soon.

Comment: But again, unless it doesn't need to be singleton then I suggest using obj.

Comment: Why is better to use obj if this is not a singleton?

Comment: What you have is singleton. Means there is only once instance of it. Which means obj will always be there. If you decide to make it not a singleton. Such as using function obj(){} where someone would do var t = obj(); then you would need to use parent or something else. But as you can see above, you only have once instance.